# Prove that the set of all unitary operators on unitary space $ \mathcal U$ is a group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Prove that the set of all unitary operators on unitary space  $ \mathcal  U$  is  a group, in particular sub-group in group of invertible linear transformations on $ \mathcal  U$.
Our course is limited to finite spaces.

My try:

Operator $U:\mathcal  U \rightarrow \mathcal  V $ is unitary $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow $ $U^*U=UU^*=I$

$$AA^*=I$$

By definition of an inverse:

$$A^{-1}=A^*$$

How do I show that a set is a sub-group in a group?

Comment: You just need to show that it is closed under the group operation and under taking inverses, so you need to show that the product of 2 unitary matrices is unitary and that the inverse of a unitary matrix is unitary.

Comment: @user84413 Thank you. Just to get things clear, is that the definition of a subgroup or is it valid just for this case? And also I would be grateful, if you could check my proof for any mistakes

Comment: This is not the definition of a subgroup, but it follows from the definition.  If H is a nonempty subset of a group G that satisfies these 2 properties, then it is a subgroup since it also satisfies the associative property and it contains the inverse e, since $a\in H\implies e=aa^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $U_n \subseteq GL_n(\mathbb C) $ I need to prove that the group is closed:

1.Under group operation (matrix multiplication)

$A,B \in U_n$

$$(AB)^*(AB)=B^*A^*AB=B^*B=I$$

$AB \in U_n$

2.Under the inverse

$A \in U_n$

as $A^{-1}=A^*$ and $AA^*=I$

$$(A^{-1})^*A^{-1}=(A^*)^*A^*=AA^*=I$$

$A^{-1} \in U_n$

Comment: In part 1, I think you want to conclude that $AB\in U_n$.